# Cannot get css span class for a drop cap to work when doing TEI. It does not validate nor work

Tags: html, css, xml, tei

CSS code:

```
.face_dropcap_ {
    font-size: 3em; 
    font-family: Palatino,serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 100%;
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 5px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
}

    <l rend="indent"> <span type=".face_dropcap_">C</span><hi rend="initial_roman">E</hi>stoit alors que le prefent des Dieux</l>
```

The hi rend works fine but when I try to embed a span class to do a drop cap in the xml, it will not work.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Hello again, While the span class works it does not validate in xml. <l rend="indent"> <span class="face_dropcap_ ">C</span><hi rend="initial_roman">E</hi>stoit alors que le prefent des <span class=".face_cap">D</span>ieux</l>

Answer (score 2):

You got to specify the classname in the HTML tag like this:

```
<span class="face_dropcap_">C</span>
```

Comment: Ahh, so stupid of me. I was including the period before .face_dropcap_ in the html/xml.  Just fixed it and got it to work.  Thanks for the fast response and simple catch!!!